# Getting the following error "PortForwardingL:local port 127.0.0.1:10005 can't be bound" while connecting to Corda Explorer UI using SSH

Tags: corda, portforwarding

Getting the following error "PortForwardingL:local port 127.0.0.1:10005 can't be bound" while connecting to corda explorer ui using SSH.

I'm not sure what port number I need to pass in "Node Port section" on Node Explorer Explorer screen?? tried giving p2p port and RPC port but didn't work out.

I have enabled the SSH server by specifying **sshd {port = 2222}** in node.conf file.

Kindly suggest whether i need to do something related to port forwarding to establish a SSH connection or something else??

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the port can't be bound is generally an issue relating to the unavailability of a port since its being used by another program. Please check if port 10005 is free.

From the node explorer side here is how you should connect to a node via SSH:

The Node Port should be the RPC port of the node. The username and password should be the RPC username and password for both SSH and RPC.

The image below is an example for connecting to a local node exposing RPC port at 10006 and SSH port at 2222.
[image]

Comment: my node is running on rpc port 10006 and giving the same port number in Node port field but still getting the same error. Tried giving p2p port and other free ports also which are not in use but no luck. May be there is some mistake in node.conf file, can you please share the same for specially this case?? Thanks!!